# Non-Homogeneous System Solver

Tags: computer-science, math-software, computer-algebra-systems

By chance does any one know if there are any nonhomogenous system of Differential equations software? I have Octave, Sage, and Python however, I have explored and seemed to find none. I am just going to illustrating the type of problem I would imagine the software to solve and leave the solution in matrix form:

\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt}=2x-y-t^2 \\ \frac{dy}{dt} = 3x +4y+t+5\end{cases}